# VB.Net DirectorySearcher returning 0 results after changing to use multiple threads

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, directoryservices

I had a single class which searches Active Directory for all OU's and then all the computer objects in them. It was working perfectly... Then I decided to utilise some threads to allow the OU search and computer object search to run simultaneously. Now all of a sudden the computer searcher is returning 0 results... (There are no errors, just simply no results)

I did also add an additional property to load (objectGUID) but I have tried removing that and it didn't fix the problem. I can't see what I've done to break it. It's probably something stupid staring me right in the face but I just can't find it. I'm hoping a fresh pair of eyes might be able to spot my mistake.

In the broken code Public Sub FindComputers(...) is where I'm having the problem.
In the working code it was Private Function FindComputers(...). I changed it as it's now in a separate class.

EDIT:
I set a breakpoint on the FindComputers sub and stepped through it. After the line queryResults = searcher.FindAll() executes, queryResults count is always 0. The events in the loop are never fired.

Thanks in advance.

## Here is the original WORKING code:

```
Public Class ADSearcher

'Removed properties and events etc

Public Sub StartSearch()

#If Not Debug Then
    Try
#End If

    Dim rootEntry As New DirectoryEntry(RootPath)
    Dim rootNode As New TreeNode(rootEntry.Name)
    rootNode.Name = rootEntry.Path

    If Not IntegratedAuthentication Then
        rootEntry.Username = UserID
        rootEntry.Password = Password
    End If

    Dim searcher As New DirectorySearcher(rootEntry)
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(PropertiesToLoad)
    searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope
    searcher.PageSize = PageSize
    searcher.ServerTimeLimit = New TimeSpan(0, 10, 0)
    searcher.Filter = FilterString

    Dim queryResults As SearchResultCollection
    queryResults = searcher.FindAll()

    Dim result As SearchResult
    For Each result In queryResults

        FindComputers(result) 'Search the current OU for computer objects

        Dim childNode As New TreeNode(CStr(result.Properties("name")(0)))
        childNode.Name = result.Path
        rootNode.Nodes.Add(SearchSub(result, childNode))

        ouResultCount += 1
        RaiseEvent ResultFound(ouResultCount, pcResultCount)
    Next

    RaiseEvent SearchCompleted(rootNode)
    ouResultCount = 0 'Reset the result count
    pcResultCount = 0 'Reset the computer result count


#If Not Debug Then
    Catch Ex as Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
#End If

End Sub

Private Function SearchSub(ByVal parent As SearchResult, ByVal node As TreeNode)
#If Not Debug Then
    Try
#End If
    Dim subEntry As New DirectoryEntry(parent.Path)

    If Not IntegratedAuthentication Then
        subEntry.Username = UserID
        subEntry.Password = Password
    End If

    Dim searcher As New DirectorySearcher(subEntry)
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(PropertiesToLoad)
    searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope
    searcher.PageSize = PageSize
    searcher.ServerTimeLimit = New TimeSpan(0, 10, 0)
    searcher.Filter = FilterString

    Dim queryResults As SearchResultCollection
    queryResults = searcher.FindAll()

    Dim result As SearchResult
    For Each result In queryResults
        FindComputers(result) 'Search for computer objects in the current OU

        Dim childNode As New TreeNode(CStr(result.Properties("name")(0)))
        childNode.Name = result.Path
        SearchSub(result, childNode)
        node.Nodes.Add(childNode)
        ouResultCount += 1
        RaiseEvent ResultFound(ouResultCount, pcResultCount)
    Next

    Return node

#If Not Debug Then
    Catch Ex as Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
#End If

End Function

Private Function FindComputers(ByVal parent As SearchResult)
#If Not Debug Then
    Try
#End If
    Dim subEntry As New DirectoryEntry(parent.Path)

    If Not IntegratedAuthentication Then
        subEntry.Username = UserID
        subEntry.Password = Password
    End If

    Dim searcher As New DirectorySearcher(subEntry)
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(PropertiesToLoad)
    searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope
    searcher.PageSize = PageSize
    searcher.ServerTimeLimit = New TimeSpan(0, 10, 0)
    searcher.Filter = "(objectCategory=computer)"

    Dim queryResults As SearchResultCollection
    queryResults = searcher.FindAll()

    Dim result As SearchResult
    For Each result In queryResults
        pcResultCount += 1

        Dim dNSHostName As String
        If result.Properties.Contains("dNSHostName") Then
            dNSHostName = result.Properties("dNSHostName")(0)
        Else
            dNSHostName = result.Properties("name")(0) 'If the computer object has a value in dNSHostName (FQDN) store it else store the basic name
        End If

        RaiseEvent ComputerFound(result.Properties("name")(0), dNSHostName, result.Path)
        RaiseEvent ResultFound(ouResultCount, pcResultCount)
    Next

    Return 1

#If Not Debug Then
    Catch Ex as Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
#End If

End Function

End Class
```

## Here is the current BROKEN code:

```
Public Class ADSearcher

'Removed properties and events etc

<MTAThread()>
Public Sub StartSearch()

#If Not Debug Then
    Try
#End If

    Dim rootEntry As New DirectoryEntry(RootPath)
    Dim rootNode As New TreeNode(rootEntry.Name)
    rootNode.Name = rootEntry.Path

    If Not IntegratedAuthentication Then
        rootEntry.Username = UserID
        rootEntry.Password = Password
    End If

    Dim searcher As New DirectorySearcher(rootEntry)
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(PropertiesToLoad)
    searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope
    searcher.PageSize = PageSize
    searcher.ServerTimeLimit = New TimeSpan(0, 10, 0)
    searcher.Filter = FilterString

    Dim queryResults As SearchResultCollection
    queryResults = searcher.FindAll()

    Dim result As SearchResult
    For Each result In queryResults

        Dim freeThread As Integer = WaitHandle.WaitAny(compSearchThreads)

        Dim threadParams As Object
        threadParams = New Object() {result, freeThread} 'Create an object to pass the parameters

        compSearchInstances(freeThread) = New ComputerSearcher(compSearchThreads(freeThread))

        With compSearchInstances(freeThread)
            .FilterString = "(objectCategory=computer)"
            If Not IntegratedAuthentication Then
                .UserID = UserID
                .Password = Password
            End If
            .PageSize = 5
            .PropertiesToLoad = New String() {"cn", "name", "distinguishedName", "dNSHostName", "objectCategory", "objectGUID"}
        End With

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf compSearchInstances(freeThread).FindComputers), threadParams)
        'FindComputers(result) 'Search the current OU for computer objects

        Dim childNode As New TreeNode(CStr(result.Properties("name")(0)))
        childNode.Name = result.Path
        childNode.Tag = result.Properties("objectGUID")(0)
        rootNode.Nodes.Add(SearchSub(result, childNode))

        ouResultCount += 1
        RaiseEvent OUResultFound(ouResultCount) ', pcResultCount)
    Next

    WaitHandle.WaitAll(compSearchThreads)
    RaiseEvent SearchCompleted(rootNode)
    ouResultCount = 0 'Reset the result count
    'pcResultCount = 0 'Reset the computer result count


#If Not Debug Then
    Catch Ex as Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
#End If

End Sub

Private Function SearchSub(ByVal parent As SearchResult, ByVal node As TreeNode)
#If Not Debug Then
    Try
#End If
    Dim subEntry As New DirectoryEntry(parent.Path)

    If Not IntegratedAuthentication Then
        subEntry.Username = UserID
        subEntry.Password = Password
    End If

    Dim searcher As New DirectorySearcher(subEntry)
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(PropertiesToLoad)
    searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope
    searcher.PageSize = PageSize
    searcher.ServerTimeLimit = New TimeSpan(0, 10, 0)
    searcher.Filter = FilterString

    Dim queryResults As SearchResultCollection
    queryResults = searcher.FindAll()

    Dim result As SearchResult
    For Each result In queryResults

        Dim freeThread As Integer = WaitHandle.WaitAny(compSearchThreads)

        Dim threadParams As Object
        threadParams = New Object() {result, freeThread} 'Create an object to pass the parameters

        compSearchInstances(freeThread) = New ComputerSearcher(compSearchThreads(freeThread))

        With compSearchInstances(freeThread)
            .FilterString = "(objectCategory=computer)"
            If Not IntegratedAuthentication Then
                .UserID = UserID
                .Password = Password
            End If
            .PageSize = 5
            .PropertiesToLoad = New String() {"cn", "name", "distinguishedName", "dNSHostName", "objectCategory", "objectGUID"}
        End With

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf compSearchInstances(freeThread).FindComputers), threadParams)

        'FindComputers(result) 'Search for computer objects in the current OU

        Dim childNode As New TreeNode(CStr(result.Properties("name")(0)))
        childNode.Name = result.Path
        childNode.Tag = result.Properties("objectGUID")(0) 'New Object() {}
        SearchSub(result, childNode)
        node.Nodes.Add(childNode)
        ouResultCount += 1
        RaiseEvent OUResultFound(ouResultCount) ', pcResultCount)
    Next

    Return node

#If Not Debug Then
    Catch Ex as Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
#End If

End Function

End Class

Public Class ComputerSearcher

'Removed properties and events etc

Public Sub FindComputers(ByVal threadParams As Object)
#If Not Debug Then
    Try
#End If

    _doneEvent.Reset() 'Signal that the thread is working

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Computer search thread " + threadParams(1).ToString + " is starting")

    Dim parent As SearchResult = threadParams(0)

    Dim subEntry As New DirectoryEntry(parent.Path)

    If Not IntegratedAuthentication Then
        subEntry.Username = UserID
        subEntry.Password = Password
    End If

    Dim searcher As New DirectorySearcher(subEntry)
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(PropertiesToLoad)
    searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope
    searcher.PageSize = PageSize
    searcher.ServerTimeLimit = New TimeSpan(0, 10, 0)
    searcher.Filter = FilterString

    Dim queryResults As SearchResultCollection
    queryResults = searcher.FindAll()

    Dim result As SearchResult
    For Each result In queryResults
        pcResultCount += 1

        Dim dNSHostName As String
        If result.Properties.Contains("dNSHostName") Then 'If the computer object has a value in dNSHostName (FQDN) store it else store the basic name
            dNSHostName = result.Properties("dNSHostName")(0)
        Else
            dNSHostName = result.Properties("name")(0)
        End If

        RaiseEvent ComputerFound(result.Properties("name")(0), dNSHostName, result.Path, result.Properties("objectGUID")(0).ToString)
        RaiseEvent CompResultFound(pcResultCount) '### TO DO: Rename event to CompIncrementResult

    Next

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Computer search thread " + threadParams(1).ToString + " is ending")
    _doneEvent.Set() 'Signal that the thread is finished

#If Not Debug Then
    Catch Ex as Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
#End If

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The key is likely in the code you did not provide, ie the event `ComputerFound`. I assume you are passing data back to it which probably puts them in a list that is either cleared each time or not scoped correctly so each list is it's own instance and by time you look at the list, it is empty because it is a new instance. Just a guess.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can give more code if needed but Should have stated that in the question, sorry. So I don't "think" it's anything outside of what I've provided but maybe that's why I'm missing it. If you need more code please let me know which functions and I will post them in the morning. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally spotted my mistake and just as I thought it was something silly staring me straight in the face. In the following section of code from StartSearch() and SubSearch() I forgot to set the SearchScope.

```
With compSearchInstances(freeThread)
    .FilterString = "(objectCategory=computer)"
    If Not IntegratedAuthentication Then
        .UserID = UserID
        .Password = Password
    End If
    .PageSize = 5
    .PropertiesToLoad = New String() {"cn", "name", "distinguishedName", "dNSHostName", "objectCategory", "objectGUID"}
End With
```

I should have had the following line in there:

```
.SearchScope = SearchScope
```